# Laptop won't restart after update without removing battery!

Tags: updates, acer, restart

This happened for a second time this morning (first was some weeks ago).

Regular update process was asking for a reboot so I agreed. My Acer V3 771 laptop then got stuck on the Acer splash screen. It didn't complain of not being able to find a boot device it just sits there.

Using the power button for a hard shut off makes no difference it just sits on the splash screen.

Removing the power and battery for a few seconds fixes the problem.

I can go through the normal shutdown/restart procedure absolutely fine. The only times I've seen this is with a software update initiated restart. I've been running Ubuntu for many years and am currently using 16.04 LTS.

Pretty weird isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Nothing to see here. Laptop was trying to boot from an old USB stick. Removing the battery simply coincided with disconnecting the USB hub.